# Same error type for all errors tracking in airbrake

Tags: angularjs, airbrake

In my angular application I defined the service as:

```
.factory('$exceptionHandler', function ($log) {
  airbrake = new airbrakeJs.Client({
    projectId: 1234,
    projectKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  });

  airbrake.addFilter(function (notice) {
    notice.context.environment = 'production';
    return notice;
  });

  return function (exception, cause) {
    $log.error(exception);
    airbrake.notify({error: exception, params: {angular_cause: cause}});
  };
});
```

This way works fine, the erros are tracking in airbrake. But all errors tracking by airbrake appear with the same error type. For example:

**Error 1**

```
Occurred at: Jan 04, 2016 13:27:13 -0200
First seen at: Jan 04, 2016 13:27:13 -0200
Occurrences: 2
URL http://localhost:8100/#/tasks
Error type: Error
Error message: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: amMomentProvider <- amMoment http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=amMomentProvider%20%3C-%20amMoment
Remote address: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
User agent: Chrome xx.x.xxxx.xxx
```

**Error 2**

```
Occurred at: Jan 04, 2016 13:28:15 -0200
First seen at: Jan 04, 2016 13:27:13 -0200
Occurrences: 2
URL http://localhost:8100/#/tasks
Error type: Error
Error message: Error: [$injector:undef] Provider '$exceptionHandler' must return a value from $get factory method. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/undef?p0=%24exceptionHandler
Remote address: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
User agent: Chrome xx.x.xxxx.xxx
```

As we can see above the two errors are of the same type and thus are grouped together as if they were the same error, but are not. How to define `Error type` differently for each different error?

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me.

```
.factory('$exceptionHandler', function ($log) {
  var airbrake = new airbrakeJs.Client({
    projectId: 1234,
    projectKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  });

  airbrake.addFilter(function (notice) {
    notice.context.environment = 'production';

    notice.errors.forEach(function (error) {
      var index  = error.message.indexOf('\n');
      error.type = error.message.substring(0, index);
    });

    return notice;
  });

  return function (exception, cause) {
    $log.error(exception);
    airbrake.notify({error: exception, params: {angular_cause: cause}});
  };
});
```